# An empty rectangle is displayed, instead of a Semantic UI icon

Tags: semantic-ui

Why is the Id Card icon of [Semantic UI](https://semantic-ui.com/elements/icon.html) displaying an empty vertical rectangle ?

```
<i class="id card icon" style="font-size: 18px;"></i>
```

I just installed the standalone package and I can see other icons being correctly displayed, like this one:

```
<i class="car icon black" style="font-size: 18px;"></i>
```

This happens on Chrome 60.0 and on Firefox 55.0 on a Linux Lubuntu 16.04 system.

It must be something with my page though, because the Semantic UI project page displays its icons just fine in my browsers.

I then thought about some conflict with some other css, and so under the Chrome debbuger I deleted all elements in my page, to end with a very bare bones page, but still, the icon would not display.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work. I downloaded the latest master from [their github project page](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI) and added the following

```
<link href="/css/semantic-ui/semantic.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

in my web page.